# Cast object pointer to char array

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, ns-3

```
unsigned char *check = NULL;
check = (dynamic_cast<unsigned char *>( ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel() ));
```

This is what I am trying. But the error is:

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel() const()’ (of type ‘class       ns3::Ptr<ns3::Channel>’) to type ‘unsigned char*’ (target is not pointer or reference to class)
```

I also tried:

```
reinterpret_cast
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` should work.

Comment: reinterpret cast is very dangrous to apply. but i have already did this. coul'nt corner the problem. at all.

Comment: What is the return type of **ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel()** ?

Comment: `code`virtual Ptr< Channel >  GetChannel (void) const =0

Comment: @alee-sindhu: So what's a `Ptr`? Without the definition of that, we can only guess how you might convert one into a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel()` is some kind of custom smart pointer; without seeing the definition of that, we can only guess at how you can convert that into a raw pointer.

Perhaps it implements a conversion operator, `operator T*()`, although that's generally regarded as a bad idea since it makes it unintended conversions too easy to do by accident. In that case, you could do:

```
void * check = ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel();
```

Otherwise, perhaps it has a member function to convert to a raw pointer. The standard smart pointers conventionally call this `get()`:

```
void * check = ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel().get();
```

If it doesn't offer that, and you really do want to get a raw pointer, then you could dereference it and take a pointer to the dereferenced object (assuming it supports dererencing; otherwise, it's a bit odd to call it a pointer at all):

```
void * check = &*ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel();
```

Once you have a `void *`, you can use `static_cast` to change it into `unsigned char *`, if that's what you want. Be careful what you do with it, since messing around with the bytes of an object can easily lead to undefined behaviour.

UPDATE: if `ns3::Ptr` is the template documented [here](http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/classns3_1_1_ptr.html), then you can get the raw pointer using:

```
void * check = PeekPointer(ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use two `static_cast` instead of `reiterpret_cast`. Beacuse the standard does not guarantee that different pointers have same size. But, the standard does guarantee that `void*` has enough size to fit pointer to any data type (except pointers to functions).

```
unsigned char *check = NULL;
check = static_cast<unsigned char*>(static_cast<void*>(ns3::NetDevice::GetChannel()));
```

Your `Ptr<Channel>` must have overloaded operator, which returns kept pointer:

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr
{
public:
  operator T*() {return _p;}

private:
  T* _p;
};
```

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: That will only work if this `Ptr` thing is convertible to `void*`. We don't have enough information to tell.

Comment: Also, the standard does guarantee that `reinterpret_cast` can convert any object pointer type to any other object pointer type and back, giving the original value; your double-cast is neither safer nor more portable than a single `reinterpret_cast`.